# Using multiple JsonParsers in one file

Tags: groovy, jackson, jsonparser

I am using Jacksons faster XML library to parse json from an input stream. I am trying to write the objects stored as a JSONArray labelled 'data' to an outputstream and assign a value of an individual json key to a variable representing a total_pages. It works when i do one or the other, however when trying to do both i get a
JsonGeneratorException: no current event to copy

the code i am currently running is as follows

```
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
        assert jsonFactory != null;
        
        //Create the main parser for the whole JSON
        JsonParser jsonParserPages = jsonFactory.createParser(inputStream);
        JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(inputStream);

        assert jsonParser != null;

        
        //Create a filtered parser poiting to a specific part of the for number of pages 
        JsonPointer jsonPointerPages = JsonPointer.compile("/pagination/total_pages");
        assert jsonPointerPages != null
        JsonParser jsonParserFilteredPages = new FilteringParserDelegate(jsonParserPages, new JsonPointerBasedFilter(jsonPointerPages), false, false);                
        assert jsonParserFilteredPages != null;
        

        jsonParserFilteredPages.nextToken()
        val = jsonParserFilteredPages.getText()
        assert val != null
        //jsonParserPages.close()
        
        //Create a filtered parser poiting to a specific part of the for data 
        JsonPointer jsonPointer = JsonPointer.compile("/data");
        JsonParser jsonParserFiltered = new FilteringParserDelegate(jsonParser, new JsonPointerBasedFilter(jsonPointer), false, false);                
        assert jsonParserFiltered != null;

        //Create the Generator
        JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = jsonFactory.createGenerator(outputStream);
        assert jsonGenerator != null;

        //Create the new JSON!
        jsonParserFiltered.nextToken();
        jsonGenerator.copyCurrentStructure(jsonParserFiltered);
        jsonGenerator.close();
```

Comment: Right off you can't pass inputStream to 2 JSON parsers.  They'll conflict with each other because the stream has only 1 read head, and can't support 2 readers reading from different parts of the stream.  Once a byte is read it's not available to another reader.  You won't be able to do that.  Reading your description I'm not sure what the output JSON should look like.  Can you post an example of the input json and expected output json?

Comment: @chubbsondubs a solution was found using the mark and reset methods of a stream. thanks for your help though

Comment: Glad you found a work around, but not all InputStreams support mark and reset.  For example, reading from a network stream would not be possible to do that as you can't replay the data from a response (unless you wrap it in a caching stream that supports mark/reset say).

Comment: True but i think for the majority of cases the solution is valid. But you are very correct and in another project i realised this way of approaching it wouldnt work

Answer (score 0):

The code below fixes the issue utilising the stream mark and reset function

String totalPages

```
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
        //Create the Factory
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
        assert jsonFactory != null;
        
        //Create the main parser for the whole JSON
        //We put a mark at the beggining of the inputstream, so we can
        //reuse it again from the beggining
        inputStream.mark(0);
        JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(inputStream);

        //Get total_pages and store it into a variable
        JsonPointer jsonPointerTotalPages = JsonPointer.compile(paginationJSONPath);
        assert jsonPointerTotalPages != null
        JsonParser jsonParserFilteredTotalPages = new FilteringParserDelegate(jsonParser, new JsonPointerBasedFilter(jsonPointerTotalPages), false, false);                
        assert jsonParserFilteredTotalPages != null;
        jsonParserFilteredTotalPages.nextToken();
        jsonParserFilteredTotalPages.nextToken();
        totalPages = jsonParserFilteredTotalPages.getText();
        assert totalPages != null;

        //Create a Generator to write the JSON
        JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = jsonFactory.createGenerator(outputStream);
        assert jsonGenerator != null;
        
        //Put the insputStream at the beggining and recreate the parser.
        inputStream.reset();
        jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(inputStream);

        //Get and write the Data
        JsonPointer jsonPointerData = JsonPointer.compile(dataJSONPath);
        assert jsonPointerData != null
        //NOTE: we use true in the FilteringParserDelegate constructor to get the key+value
        JsonParser jsonParserFilteredData = new FilteringParserDelegate(jsonParser, new JsonPointerBasedFilter(jsonPointerData), true, false);
        assert jsonParserFilteredData != null;
        jsonParserFilteredData.nextToken();
        jsonGenerator.copyCurrentStructure(jsonParserFilteredData);
        jsonGenerator.close();
        
    } as StreamCallback)
```